# Entity Framework Code First From Existing Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to achieve the opposite of [NotMapped] attribute.

I have code first mapping from existing database and I was wondering is there any way I can skip some database table columns and map only the ones which are required in my current application? The same database is used by few other applications and I don't want to upgrade my application every time somebody adds a few columns. I know its a mess.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, if the database table has 3 columns and you only implement 2 in your entity definition, you won't have any problems

Comment: @garethb: I thought that as well but when I run my application it throws an exception: "Unknown column 'Extent1.UNMAPPED_COLUMN_NAME' in 'field list' "

Comment: _"Entity Framework Code First From Existing Database"_ - isn't that an _oxymoron_?

Comment: @MickyD: God knows I'd love to use our existing DB, pull out the schema into code-first instead and throw away the model-first jumble...

Comment: @Ali Don't use any Visual Studio tools/smarts like code first / database first. Do it manually. Just define your entities with the columns you require, your DataContext (all the dbsets) and your connection string. The initial setup takes a bit longer but well worth it IMO as you have full control over your data model, not what some tool thinks you need!

Comment: @garethb yep did that and it worked. Thanks.